# Javamail: compiling error

Tags: java, import, jakarta-mail

I am creating a program that randomly pairs people for a game of Assassin. After pairing people, it should email them to tell them who their paired "Target" is. 
  I know my panel looks messy when you run it, but my main issue is that the JavaMail API I am using to alert people of their "target" is not working. 
  My IDE is not accepting JavaMail as an import. I have downloaded the necessary files from GitHub, but It still does not work. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class AGP extends JPanel {
    int playCount = 0;
    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> GMs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> GMEs = new ArrayList<String>();
    JButton addPlayer = new JButton("add Player");
    JButton startGame = new JButton("Start Game");
    JLabel pC = new JLabel("Players: " + playCount);
    JLabel pN = new JLabel("Name here");
    JLabel eM = new JLabel("email here");
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JTextField name = new JTextField();
    JTextField email = new JTextField();
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    JButton GM = new JButton("Add Game Master");

    public AGP() {
        addPlayer.addActionListener(new Listener1());
        startGame.addActionListener(new Listener2());
        GM.addActionListener(new Listener3());
        setLayout(layout);
        c.gridwidth = 300;
        c.ipadx = 385;
        c.ipady = 20;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        add(pC, c);
        c.ipadx = 275;
        c.ipady = 50;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(pN, c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        add(name, c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        add(eM);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        add(email);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        add(addPlayer);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        add(startGame);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        add(GM);
    }

    private class Listener1 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (!(name.getText() == "") && !(email.getText() == "")) {
                players.add(name.getText());
                Emails.add(email.getText());
                playCount++;
                name.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                pC.setText("Players: " + playCount);
            } else {
                pC.setText("Missing name or email");
            }
        }
    }

    private class Listener2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (players.size() % 2 == 0 && Emails.size() % 2 == 0) {
                String[] atk = new String[players.size()];
                String[] attackers = new String[players.size()];
                String[] targets = new String[players.size()];
                players.toArray(atk);
                for (int x = 1; x < playCount; x++) {
                    attackers[x] = atk[(int) (Math.random() * (atk.length + 1))];
                    for (int y = 1; y < attackers.length; y++) {
                        if (attackers[x] == attackers[y]) {
                            attackers[x] = atk[(int) (Math.random() * (atk.length + 1))];
                        }
                    }
                    for (int z = 1; z < playCount; z++) {
                        targets[z] = atk[(int) (Math.random() * (atk.length + 1))];
                        for (int r = 1; r < targets.length; r++) {
                            if (targets[z] == targets[r]) {
                                targets[z] = atk[(int) (Math.random() * (atk.length + 1))];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    String[] ems = new String[Emails.size()];
                    String[] gMEs = new String[GMEs.size()];
                    GMEs.toArray(gMEs);
                    Emails.toArray(ems);

                                  for(int g =1; g<attackers.length(); g++{ for(int h =1;
                      h<atk.length; h++){ if(attackers[g]==players[h]){ String
                      host = "localhost" Properties properties =
                      System.getProperties(); Session session =
                      Session.getDefaultInstance(properties); try{ MimeMessage
                      message = new MimeMessage(session); message.setFrom(new
                      InternetAddress(gMEs[(int)(Math.random()*(gMEs.size()+1)]
                      )); message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new
                      InternetAddress(ems[h]));
                      message.setSubject("Game at CNU 'Assasins'");
                      message.setText("Welcome to the game "+attackers[h]
                      +"Your first target is: "+target[h]+"have fun!");
                      Transport.send(message); } message.setRecipients("");
                      mex.printStackTrace(); } } } } for(int p=1; p<gMEs.size;
                      p++){ message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new
                      InternetAddress(gMEs[p])); message.setText(for(int x=1;
                      x<=attackers.length()x++){attackers[x]+"is looking for"
                      +targets[x]}; Transport.send(message); }
                      catch(MessagingException mex){ mex.printStackTrace(); } }
                      } } }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class Listener3 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (!(name.getText() == "") && !(email.getText() == "")) {
                GMs.add(name.getText());
                GMEs.add(email.getText());
                name.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                pC.setText("Players: " + playCount);
            } else {
                pC.setText("Missing name or email");
            }
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Assasins Game generator v1");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setContentPane(new AGP());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

How do I get Eclipse to accept the import?

Comment: Does this [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#libeclipse) entry help?

Comment: It does not apparently. I followed the instructions, but Eclipse sees an error in the User Library I created.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. There was a an issue with my handling of the procedure, but things are now working correctly.